# Make 'Log On To' Active Directory setting permanent

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, user-management, windows-server-essentials

In Active Directory (Windows EBS Server 2008 testing envionment), I have set a user the ability to log onto all computers. (Eg: Properties of User -> Account tab -> Log On To button -> Select All Computers option) This is all fine but the setting is being reset to the default option at odd intervals.

Is there some kind of policy setting that is making this revert? or something else? This option is preventing the test user from logging into their local workstation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening is that the user setting that is being altered has no CAL installed.

After assigning the test user a temporary CAL the setting then reverts to normal behavior.

EDIT: [I found a blog post that details the problem I had.](http://blogs.technet.com/essentialbusinessserver/archive/2009/10/12/understanding-ebs-client-licensing.aspx) It also explains how CALs operate in EBS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the setting to allow logons to all computers IS the default option. What is it being "reset" to in your case?

Comment: Thats what I thought. It is being set to the other 'The following computers' and it lists the three default servers that you install with EBS 2008. I just created a new user and it is set to All Computers. Ill have to wait and see if it changes.